# Size characterization

Tags: materials, chemical-engineering, material-science, biomedical-engineering, chemistry

Which technique can I use to characterize the size of my particles?  They would be in the range of 50 μm to 300 μm. I have verified using a microscope, but I need a technique to analyse the size distribution. Particles are in a suspension.

Comment: Have you found anything so far? So we don't suggest things you have already found and discarded...

Comment: I ve' discussed the problem with couple of researchers, they suggested, best thing to use would be microscopy, which I am already using.